# Golang HTTP request retry code

Tags: http, go

I believe that clean and elegant retry code is notoriously difficult, so I'm wondering how the following code could be improved. The `retryGet` function should have the same interface and contract as `http.Get`, except for the number of attempts argument, of course.

```
func retryGet(url string, maxAttempts int) (*http.Response, error) {
    attempts := 0

    if maxAttempts < 1 {
        return nil, errors.New("maxAttempts must be at least 1")
    }

    for {
        attempts++
        response, err := http.Get(url)
        if err == nil && response.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
            return response, nil
        }

        delay, retry := shouldRetry(maxAttempts, attempts, response)
        if !retry {
            return response, err
        }

        if err == nil {
            defer response.Body.Close()
        }

        time.Sleep(delay)
    }
}

func shouldRetry(maxAttempts, attempts int, response *http.Response) (time.Duration, bool) {
    if attempts >= maxAttempts {
        return time.Duration(0), false
    }

    delay := time.Duration(attempts) * time.Second

    if response != nil && response.Header.Get("Retry-After") != "" {
        after, err := strconv.ParseInt(response.Header.Get("Retry-After"), 10, 64)
        if err != nil && after > 0 {
            delay = time.Duration(after) * time.Second
        }
    }

    return delay, true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to actually strictly match the [http.Get](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client.Get) signature using a struct:

```
type Getter func(url string) (*http.Response, error)

type RetryingClient struct {
    Getter Getter
    MaxAttempts int
}

func (rc RetryingClient) Get(url string) (*http.Response, error) {
    ...
}
```

And instead of directly calling `http.Get`, the embedded `Getter` interface gives you much more flexibility:

- for testing
- for using a proxy

---

Why do you `defer` the `response.Body.Close()` ? Since it won't be use, you can close it immediately.

---

Using the interface, you could make a function embedded in the struct to compute a default delay instead of hard-coded `time.Duration(attempts) * time.Second`.
For instance: `defaultDelay(attempt int) time.Duration`